# SaveChanges on removed entity throws DuplicateKeyException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I create an entity object and store it in the database. Then I create a second one with the same PrimaryKey value (from a timestamp and an id column), but different content. Adding this to the DbContext throws 'InvalidOperationException', so I catch that and do a `context.Update(obj)`. Now the `SaveChanges()` throws a 'DbUpdateException', where the InnerException shows a 'DuplicateKeyException', but objects state is 'Modified'.

At this point, I try to delete the old record and store the new, but `SaveChanges(true)` already throws 'DbUpdateException->DuplicateKeyException' after `context.Remove(obj)`.

I try to do this in a separate Transaction with two `SaveChanges(true)` calls, but the first failed.

Didn't find a solution in StackOverflow nor MS documentation.

Here some example 'lookalike'-code:

```
// Example Model-Class
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; } // this and ...
    public int id { get; set; }             // this is the PrimaryKey in DB and DbContext classes
    public String Data { get; set;}
}
:
:
// Do the work somewhere
MyEntity entity1 = CreateEntity(new DateTime(2020,1,1,0,0,0), 1, "Ape");
SaveMyStuff(entity1, false);

MyEntity entity2 = CreateEntity(new DateTime(2020,1,1,0,0,0), 1, "Ape");
try {
    SaveMyStuff(entity2. false);
}catch(InvalidOperationException iOpEx)
{ /* Expected this, so do nothing */ }

MyEntity entity3 = CreateEntity(new DateTime(2020,1,1,0,0,0), 1, "Monkey");
SaveMyStuff(entity3, true); // <-- FAIL
:
:

public void SaveMyStuff(MyEntity entity, bool Overwrite)
{
    MyDbContext context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>(); // via AddDbContextPool()
    try {
        context.Add(entity);
    }catch (InvalidOperationException iOpEx)
    {
        if( Overwrite )
        {
            // If the context already know entity's primary keys, do a update instead
            context.Update(entity);
        }
        else
            throw iOpEx;
    }
    try {
        context.SaveChanges(true);
    }catch(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException dbUpdEx)
    {
        if( Overwrite )
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                context.Remove(entity);
                context.SaveChanges(true); // <-- throws DuplicateKeyException
                context.Add(entity);
                context.SaveChanges(true);
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        else
            throw dbUpdEx;
    }
}
```

Did I miss some patterns or HowTo's to do such stuff?

Comment: Any reason why you are using Exceptions for flow instead of checking if the entity is in the DB?

Comment: @MarkPM Probably because an `if-exists` check is useless ([race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software)). Better just try and handle any exceptions. The way Buckaroo Banzi uses them, though, is pretty messy... to say the least.

Comment: @RobIII: It's messy, because it's a example.... in normal usage I ignore duplicate keys for this part, because it's a importer without user action.
My question was, why removing a entity throws a exception?

Comment: `It's messy, because it's a example....` if it's an example then it [_shouldn't_ be messy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).